# mysql manipulate result, replace string

Tags: mysql

I have a table

```
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
| category_id | parent_category_id |    category_path     |        category_name        |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
|       13098 |                  0 | 0                    | Scooter 100cc+              |
|       13099 |              13098 | 0,13098,             | Aprilia                     |
|       13100 |              13099 | 0,13098,13099,       | Atlantic/Arrecife 125 LC 4T |
|       13101 |              13100 | 0,13098,13099,13100, | Fahrwerk                    |
+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Is there a way in MySQL to construct the `category_path` as a replacement in the `category_path` field?
So on the last line in the `category_path` field there is

```
|Scooter 100cc, Aprilia, Atlantic/Arecife 125 LC 4T|
```

instead of

```
|0,13098,13099,13100|
```

Comment: You should never store comma separated values in one column. Read about normalization and redesign your database. You will spare yourself a lot of trouble. Plus, you will find an easy solution for this question. In this form it's so much trouble to solve, that I definitely don't want to do it.

Comment: it is a commercial product which is designed as it is and i can not do anything the table structure. i just need to import thousands of records into the database and this part is one of the latest steps i need to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You should really think of optimizing the database and normalize it, since storing data as comma separated data will lead you to many problems in future.

Its better to create an association table and store one-to-many record per category in to that table.

However in the current situation you can use `find_in_set()` as

```
select 
c1.category_id,
c1.parent_category_id,
group_concat(c2.category_name) as category_path, 
c1.category_name 
from category c1 
left join category c2 on find_in_set(t2.parent_category_id,c1.category_path) 
group by c1.category_id;
```

Comment: this manipulates the data but not the correct way.  i will try to elaborate on this. thank you